# When running HBase on amazon EMR, why does /tmp folder is huge compared to the actual data?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, amazon-emr

We have a hadoop+hbase cluster on amazon EMR with the default configuration, so that both `mapred.child.tmp` and `hbase.tmp.dir` point to `/tmp`. Our cluster has been running for a while and now `/tmp` is 500Gb, compared to 70Gb for actual `/hbase` data.

This kind of difference seems too much, are we supposed to periodically delete some of the `/tmp` data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I found that the largest part of our `/tmp` data was created by failed mapreduce tasks during Amazon's automatic backup of Hbase to S3. Our successful mapreduce tasks don't leave much data in `/tmp`.

We have decided to disable Amazon's automatic backup and implement our own backup script using Hbase tool for importing/exporting tables.